# How to call a function from java socket to Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have the following script that connects without problems from JavaScript ( as client) to a function in Node.js server by socket.io that has the following code . But I have no idea what to call this same function (conremot.sockets.on("connection",recibeSMS);) from a java client.

**client JavaScript**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> < / script >
    <script src="http://ec2-54-205-191-244.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6969/socket.io/socket.io.js"> < / script >

<script>
var websocket = io . connect ( " http://ec2-54-205-191-244.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6969 ");
$ (document ) on ( "ready" , start ) . ;
}
SendMsj function ( e)
{

     e.preventDefault ( ) ;
websocket.emit ( " nuevoMensaje ", " Hello SMS" );
websocket.on ( 'connect ', function () {
} ) ;

}


< / script >
< / head>
```

**Node.js server**

```
    conremot var = require (" socket.io " ) listen ( 6969 ) ;

    conremot.sockets.on ( " connection" , recibeSMS );

/ / Receiving variables :

    recibeSMS function (user)
     {
        usuario.on ( " nuevoMensaje " emitirSMS ) ;
     }


/ / Sending variables :

    emitirSMS function (sms )
    {
        conremot.sockets.emit ( " SMS_DesdeServidor " sms) ;
    }
```

**Thank you in advance for your support .**

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client). Not to be rude or anything but next time try to google because this was the first result I got when I entered '`socket.io java client`' :)